# SWIFT 3 Post request with VIEWSTATE

Tags: asp.net, swift, post

I need to log in example.com/mobile/shared/default.aspx by using POST request

How do i get current ViewState and sending it after?

**That is what i tried** 
(Alamofire)

```
func webRequest()
{
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "name": "name",
        "password": "password",
        "enter": "Enter",

    ]


    Alamofire.request("http://example.ru/mobile/shared/default.aspx", parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }



}
}
```

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: @GClovs yes, that was pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Alamofire like this:

```
let Parameters      = [
       "name": "name",
       "password": "password",
       "enter": "Enter"]
var json : JSON     = nil
Alamofire.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: Parameters)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    json = JSON(data)
                    print(json)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                }
        }


 }
```

So after that you can parse your json like this for example:

```
if json != nil {
 let token = json["token"].stringValue
}
```

But all of that depend of your server request params, and request response from your server.
Hope I helped you, Peace